# <table> multiple row height WOES

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've searched around here and elsewhere to for a solution to this problem, but nothing I've tried has worked.  The googleplex abounds with samples, but many just don't seem to fit my needs or depend heavily on tricks I can't understand.

Basically, I am trying to create a dashboard. I gave up on .css when I couldn't get things even. I have 3 rows. The most amount of columns per row is 3, and one row will be 2/3 and 1/3, and another row will be 50/50 (top row is 1/3, 1/3 and 1/3). When I couldn't get .css to have the columns even (the third 1/3 was shifting down, or off center from the rest of the row), I switched to .

When there was limited content in the tiles in the dashboard I was able to get the columns/rows distributed evenly (using width/height: 33.3%). If I resized the browser the tiles shrunk to a point where (as expected) if the window was minimized to much left/right only some of the tiles appeared.  Not great - I was hoping that even if the content disappeared that I could minimize left/right as far as the browser would let me and see 3 equal columns || || || like that.  But ok, no biggie.

Well, I put content in the bottom left tile (3x3 tile grid) and of course it expanded.  Now I tried everything (border-collapse, white-space, overflow: hidden, etc.) and still can't get it the way I want.

I am stumped.  I understand that at a certain point the browser is going to force things to overflow (lets say arbitrarily this should happen at 800x600), but I was hoping my display would shrink appropriately (tiles get smaller equally) and that the scrollbars inside the tiles would show up on the y-axis (overflow-y) so the user could scroll the text.  I even tried 800x600 min/max width/height, but I couldn't get it to work.

Any advice would be appreciated.

This is my html snippet:

```
<div id="dashboard">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
            <td class="dashboard-tile onethird">
                <div id="Alerts">
                    <div class="content">
                        <header> <span>Alerts</span> </header>
                        <section> Content Here </section>
                        <footer> Link </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="dashboard-tile onethird">
                <div id="Matters">
                    <div class="content">
                        <header> <span>Matters</span> </header>
                        <section> Content Here </section>
                        <footer> Link </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="dashboard-tile onethird">
                <div id="RecentActivity">
                    <div class="content">
                        <header> <span>Recent Activity</span> </header>
                        <section> Content Here </section>
                        <footer> Link </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="dashboard-tile onethird">
                <div id="Alerts">
                    <div class="content">
                        <header> <span>Alerts</span> </header>
                        <section> Content Here </section>
                        <footer> Link </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="dashboard-tile onethird">
                <div id="Matters">
                    <div class="content">
                        <header> <span>Matters</span> </header>
                        <section> Content Here </section>
                        <footer> Link </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="dashboard-tile onethird">
                <div id="RecentActivity">
                    <div class="content">
                        <header> <span>Recent Activity</span> </header>
                        <section> Content Here </section>
                        <footer> Link </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="dashboard-tile onethird">
                <div id="Alerts">
                    <div class="content">
                        <header> <span>Alerts</span> </header>
                        <section> Content HereContent Here Content HereContent Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content HereContent Here Content HereContent Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content HereContent Here Content HereContent Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content Here Content HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent HereContent Here Content Here Content Here Content Here </section>
                        <footer> Link </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="dashboard-tile onethird">
                <div id="Matters">
                    <div class="content">
                        <header> <span>Matters</span> </header>
                        <section> Content Here </section>
                        <footer> Link </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="dashboard-tile onethird">
                <div id="RecentActivity">
                    <div class="content">
                        <header> <span>Recent Activity</span> </header>
                        <section> Content Here </section>
                        <footer> Link </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is my .css:

```
#dashboard { height: 100%; }
#dashboard table { height: 100%; width: 100%; border:0; margin: 0px; padding: 0; }
#dashboard table tr { height: 33.3%;  }
#dashboard table td { vertical-align: top; height: 33.3%; min-width: 33.3%; min-height: 33.3%; max-width: 33.3%; max-height: 33.3%; overflow: hidden;  }
#dashboard table td.onethird { width: 33.3%; }
.dashboard-tile { background-color: #650000; border: 1px solid #790000; }

.dashboard-tile .half {}
.dashboard-tile .twothird {}
.dashboard-tile .full {}
.dashboard-tile .content { margin: 5px 10px; overflow-y: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; color:#fff; } 
.dashboard-tile header { font-size: 1.3em; font-weight:bold; width:100%; float:left; padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px; }
.dashboard-tile header span { float: left; text-transform: uppercase; }  

.dashboard-tile section { margin-top:35px; }

.dashboard-tile footer{ }
.dashboard-tile footer span { font-weight:bold; }
```

Comment: I don't see tabular data here, correct me if I'm wrong. If it isn't tabular data, stop forcing it.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an image of what you'd like to achieve? Using tables for non-tabular data is not a solution, and we can help you better if we know exactly what you need.

Comment: I agree <table> usage for presentation is wrong. It did, for the most part accomplish what I needed temporarily. @bookcasey your second demo below got it done right. I had a similar solution but too many <div> elements was making it act strange. Goes to show, simple trumps complicated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really not clear what you want, but I'm going to try to answer anyway.

It's fairly simple to make a fluid design with thirds and halves.

```
li{ width:33%; float:left;}
```

or alternatively,

```
li{ width:50%; float:left;}
```

Also, on a small screen, dividing text into three columns is not ideal for legibility. Consider using media queries like this:

```
 @media screen and (max-width:600px){
      li{width:100%}
  }
```

To simplify layouts for small screens.

Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/9PynE/) of the above concepts.

**EDIT:**

Here is a slightly different and simplified solution:

```
html{height:100%;}
body{height:100%;}
div{width:33.333333%; height:33.333333%; float:left; overflow:auto;}
.twothirds{width:66.666666%;}
.half{width:50%;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andgt/)

Comment: Sorry if my explanation was a bit off. Thanks for going through the (what I imagine you would consider trivial but I consider a big deal) effort. What you presented is intriguing I like the way the layout switches to the standard top down list once the window gets too small. There are a few problems. I'm using ASP.net MVC so providing you with a reciprocal jfiddle is a bit more complicated the way I separate out everything. First, the rows don't equally distribute on full screen. Second, when I start left/right minimizing window, some of the text goes outside the "box".

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "when I start left/right minimizing window", but I made another example. Does that look right?

Comment: Sorry, I mean minimizing the browser window horizontally (as opposed to vertically (up/down) or diagonally) to see the how the content is resized.

Comment: That appears to work very well, thank you for your efforts. +1 for using JSFiddle.

Comment: Always round down with percentages (ex. 66% not 67 or 66.66) and use `box-sizing: border-box` to prevent the boxes from freaking out if you use padding, etc. `box-sizing` support starts with IE8 (and IE5.5 on mac if you want to get technical :P). Other than that, which is my opinion, good answer @bookcasey

Comment: @KevinPeno Just coming back here to ask about my boxes freaking out because I am running into problems with padding/margins. I want spacing between the colored tiles and tried using inner divs to hold content but I encountering problems. What's a solution for older browsers?

Comment: @MEMoriarty there is no solution. If you need it to be supported beyond IE8 you will need not apply margins, borders, or padding to the wrapping elements. Instead have container elements inside of those that apply padding/borders. Don't use margins unless you set `overflow: hidden` on the wrapping `div`s as the margins will collapse. The only other option is quirks mode, but that is obviously not advisable.

Comment: @KevinPeno  My problem is that with an inner <div> if I give that a "background-color" (and not to the parent <div>), then it does NOT fill up the height, which defeats the purpose of bookcasey's solution.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/7323-box-sizing/ was helpful with box-sizing (although more to the point about <textarea>)

Comment: @MEMoriarty you can set background colors and whatnot on the outer divs. Just don't apply things that will alter layout to them (i.e. margin, padding, and borders).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5533/discussion-between-kevin-peno-and-m-e-moriarty)